# Linq average of list with all its nested list values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<A>`. Each `A` has a `List<B>` where `B` has an int `x`. I am trying to calculate the average value of `x` for all `A`.

I have tried:

```
@Model.AList.ForEach(a => a.BList.Average(b => b.x))
```

This complains about missing a return value. I've experimented with something like:

```
@Model.Alist.ForEach(a =>
{
    return a.Blist.Average(b => b.x);
})
```

But this is incorrect syntax since `ForEach` expects void return.

How can I calculate the average value of `x` for all `A` usin a LINQ query?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "for all A" more explicitly, are you expecting a single total average or a list of average? If you expect only one total average does the number of items en each list affect the result?

Comment: Haha, downvoting a question 10 minutes after an accepted answer with 6 upvotes has been accepted. Nice one. `average of list with all its nested list values` indicates to me 1 average value is sought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First flatten the collection, then take the average.  Something like this:

```
@Model.AList.SelectMany(a => a.BList).Average(b => b.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean you want the different averages for each BList, so here's that solution:

```
@Model.AList.Select(a => a.BList.Average(b => b.x))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also very useful but not what I meand in the question. This creates an enumerable of the averages right?